Unable to connect to the Gitlab webpage from my laptop
Current situation:
My laptop SSH > Docker vm > gitlab (docker container).
I'm able to SSH to the docker vm, and have installed docker, and used the gitlab latest image to create the required containers (Web and Runner). I'm currently using a docker-compose.yaml file. That file has some configuration of the gitlab server that I'm trying to host internally for my company.
However, I'm unable to reach the docker container from my system. It seems like I'm misunderstanding something and am unable to resolve it. Does anyone have an idea how I would be able to http:// or https:// to the container name (DNS) so that it would be accessible for other people in our company?
Current docker-compose.yaml configuration:
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    container_name: gitlab
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://localhost'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - gitlab

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner'
    networks:
      - gitlab

networks:
  gitlab:
    name: gitlab-network
    external: true

